# How do I use the logical NOT (!) operator when invoking functions in JS?

Tags: javascript, operators, underscore.js, logical-operators

I'm re-creating functions from the underscore library but I'm running into a roadblock while trying to implement the `_.reject()` function. For the purposes of this question, I'll include the code I've written for three functions: `_.each()`, `_.filter()`, and `_.reject()`.

```
_.each = function(collection, iterator) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  } else {
    for (var i in collection) {
      iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  }
};

_.filter = function(collection, test) {
    var results = [];

    _.each(collection, function(i) {
      if (test(i)) {
        results.push(i);
      }
    })

    return results;
};
```

And here's the code for the function that I'm getting a problem with, the `_.reject()` method, along with the `isEven()` function that I'm passing in as the `test` argument.

```
_.reject = function(collection, test) {
    return _.filter(collection, !test);
}; 

var isEven = function(x) {
    if (x % 2 === 0) return true;
    return false;
};
```

According to [MDN's page on Expressions and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), the Logical NOT (!) operator `Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.`

But when I run the following code `_.reject([1,2,3], isEven)` I get an error saying that `test is not a function`. Why am I unable to use the `!` operator while invoking a function (e.g., `_.filter([1,2,3], !isEven)`)?

Comment: Sounds like perhaps you want `!test()` instead. Negating a function is meaningless. Negating a function's return value is more useful.

Comment: Ah, I thought that negating the function a la `!isEven` would negate the return value.

Comment: I've posted an answer that may provide a solution. let me know how that goes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you refer to a function, rather than calling it, you're referring to the function's object reference:

```
function foo() {
    alert("Hi there");
}

var f = foo; // <== Getting the function's reference, not calling it
f();         // <== Now we call it
```

So `!isEven` would be negating the function reference. Since `isEven` is a non-`null` reference, it's truthy; and so `!isEven` is `false`. Not what you want. :-)

Your `reject` could be written with a function that calls `test` and inverts its return value:

```
_.reject = function(collection, test) {
  return _.filter(collection, function(e) { return !test(e); });
};
```

Or if you want to go the functional programming approach, you can write a function that, when called, will return a *new* function that negates the return value:

```
function not(f) {
    return function() {
        return !f.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Then anywhere you want to invert a callback's meaning, you'd just use `invert`:

```
_.reject = function(collection, test) {
  return _.filter(collection, not(test));
};
```

Answer (score 7):

> Why am I unable to use the `!` operator while invoking a function (e.g., `_.filter([1,2,3], !isEven))`?

Note that you are actually not invoking `isEven`, you are merely referencing it. As you said, `!` *"Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true."*

`isEven` is a reference to a function, i.e. an object. Objects convert to `true`, hence `!test` results in `false`:

```
_.filter([1,2,3], false))
```

Now you are passing a Boolean instead of a function to `_.filter`, hence the error message *"test is not a function"*.

Instead, you have to pass a function that negates the result of the test function:

```
_.filter([1,2,3], function() {
    return !test.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot negate a function. It's a meaningless thing to do (unless you really want the value `false` without typing it). Instead you want to negate the function's return value. I suspect what you want is something like so

```
_.reject = function(collection, test) {
  return _.filter(collection, function(e) { return !test(e); });
}
```